# prevent webpicmd from sending output to new window in windows 8

Tags: web-platform-installer

After installing the latest version of WebPICmd.exe from the chocolatey gallery (https://chocolatey.org/packages/webpicommandline, 7.1.1374) on windows 8 I am not able to use the problem.  For some reason the command output is going to a new console window, which immediately closes.  I am running the command from PowerShell.

On Windows 7, it behaves nicely and the output of webpicmd.exe goes to my current window.  I cannot imagine why it would work otherwise for windows 8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you try launching your CMD (One you run WebPICmd in) as Administrator.

Comment: That was it.  Even with UAC turned off this was necessary, which wasn't the case with Windows 7.